# http://gis.stackexchange.com vs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gis

Tags: discussion

What's the difference between this GIS site & the generic StackOverflow GIS tagged questions?

This one looks like it's more mapy, but ultimately when I'm looking for an answer to a question where should I post it?

http://gis.stackexchange.com 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gis

I'm also looking for information specifically on OpenLayers.

Comment: What does mapy mean?

Answer (score 12):

If it's got to do with GIS ask it here. I see a lot of openlayers and GIS questions on SO.SE that are poorly answered, if at all. And 9 times out of 10 I think to myself "they should have asked it on GIS.SE, and sometimes I recommend it. I get a lot more responses and quality responses from people who really know GIS. Just my experience.

Answer (score 3):

I think it probably depends on the type of answer or speed you want it answered.
The [FAQ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/faq) for gis.stackexchange.com should describe the type of questions that are appropriate to ask here.
Stackexchange certainly has some attention of our users and others capable of answering gis questions.

Comment: The Tour/FAQ has two lines detailing that, and IMO it leaves too much room for interpretation (meaning disagreement between posters and the mods who close their posts). Personally it has felt frustrating for me when I read those lines and believed my question was within topic, but then was closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that GIS.SE is "more mapy" - especially in the sense of being more *map API* oriented.

If you have a question about a coding problem not related to the geospatial aspect of an application you're developing, I'd say you're better off on SO.